Supabase Delete user from auth if failed user creation in database during sign up
I am using supabase authentication for sign up, and when a user successfully signs up, I am inserting a row in a "profiles" table that consists of other user details.
I want to handle the case where a user successfully signs up with supabase auth, but fails to get inserted in profiles table. If that happens, I want to delete the account created in auth. How do I do this? Is there a better approach for this?
"use server";

import { revalidatePath } from "next/cache";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";
import { createClient } from "@/utils/supabase/server";

export async function register(data: {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
}) {
  const supabase = createClient();

  // Auth Sign Up
  const { data: authData, error: authError } = await supabase.auth.signUp({
    email: data.email,
    password: data.password,
    options: {
      data: { displayName: data.name },
    },
  });

  if (authError) return { error: authError.message };

  // Create new User Profile
  const { error } = await supabase.from("profiles").insert({
    id: authData.user?.id,
    email: data.email,
    username: data.name,
    display_name: data.name,
  });

  if (error) {
    // Remove user created in auth
    // How do I do this?

    return { error: error.message };
  }

  revalidatePath("/", "layout");
  redirect("/messages");
}


So I found two solutions.
Firstly, I may not need to create a profiles table since I can store everything in user's metadata in auth: https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/managing-user-data#accessing-user-metadata
Secondly, if I still want to have a profiles table, I can use supabase triggers which will automatically insert a row in profiles table upon user creation via auth. Link: https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/managing-user-data#using-triggers
If I am using triggers, I don't need to manually write this code either. In my supabase project, I go to SQL Editor > Quickstarts > User Management Starters. This will write the query for me with Profile Creations, Policies and Triggers. I just have to run the query and it's all done!

To delete an user you have to create a Supabase instance with the service role key. It will not work with the anon key. Do not expose your key in the client side.
https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/auth-admin-deleteuser

You said I shouldn't expose my key in the client side, does that include server actions of next.js? Is there a better approach for what I'm trying to do?

Yes. You are correct. When you are on server actions the methods that you use from Supabase general have Client on there name. It's to remind us that it is still expose. The best approach is to use edge functions. Link with an example: https://blog.mansueli.com/supabase-user-self-deletion-empower-users-with-edge-functions

You Can use your keys in server actions in nextjs as those will not be exposed publicly, it's perfectly safe to do so.

I thought that it wasn't safe to use service role key in server side. Can you indicate me a reference to docs? I was reading this link https://supabase.com/docs/guides/api/API-keys and they say "private server".

I think that "Create_profile" trigger which run after record is adde into auth.users is connected with user creation so if this trigger will fail the whole proces will fail. You will get an error during auth.signup()
Please dont delete users from client... Its a very bad idea. If you need to delete profile just create a postrgres function and execute it from server.

I didn't understand the first part of your answer. What do you mean by "I think that "Create_profile" trigger which run after record is adde into auth.users is connected with user creation"?

It looks like you found a solution which I proposed:
"Secondly, if I still want to have a profiles table, I can use supabase triggers which will automatically insert a row in profiles table upon user creation via auth"
Trigger and user creation is connected so if one of them fail all of them gonna fail.
